# MSYS2 - Install gcc or toolchain?

Tags: gcc, mingw, toolchain, msys2

I am using Portable MSYS2 + MinGW64.
I mean to get gcc.

Some sources indicate installing `gcc`, e.g.

```
$ pacman -Sy mingw-w64-i686-gcc
$ pacman -Sy mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/227005/

Others (mostly in github) indicate installing a `toolchain`, e.g.

```
$ pacman -Sy mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

https://github.com/tpaviot/oce/issues/631

https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues/293

https://github.com/orlp/dev-on-windows/wiki/Installing-GCC--&-MSYS2

**What are the reasons, if any, for preferring one or the other?**

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Found on the [mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/31660952/):

```
Then you can install toolchain by typing:
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-toolchain
or
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
It installs full MinGW-w64 GCC with prerequisites. If you don't need full
GCC then you can install only needed languages. Variants are:
32bit:
mingw-w64-i686-gcc  - C/C++
mingw-w64-i686-ada
mingw-w64-i686-fortran
mingw-w64-i686-objc  - ObjC/ObjC++

64bit:
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc  - C/C++
mingw-w64-x86_64-ada
mingw-w64-x86_64-fortran
mingw-w64-x86_64-objc  - ObjC/ObjC++
```

So the toolchain installs all available languages, not just gcc.

Comment: Concise! Then I need the toolchain. I will try it and post feedback.